# Using Pagination and Pull To Refresh with a UITableViewDiffableDataSource

Tags: swift, uitableview, diffabledatasource, uitableviewdiffabledatasource

I have `UITableViewController` that supports both pagination and pull to refresh.

I am trying to understand the correct way to handle

1. Replacing all the data - *pull to refresh*
2. Append new items - *pagination*

I have an update method like the below.

When the data is updated from a pull to refresh or loaded for the first time, the `refresh` flag is `true` and on a pagination update it is `false`.

```swift
func update(with list: UserList, animate: Bool = true, refresh: Bool) {

  var snapshot: NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, UserList>

  if refresh {
    snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, UserList>()
    snapshot.appendSections(Section.allCases)
  } else {
    snapshot = dataSource.snapshot()
  }

  snapshot.appendItems(list.active, toSection: .active)
  dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: animate)
}
```

I am unsure if this is correct.

I am creating a new empty snapshot on refresh, appending sections, adding items and applying.

On pagination I am grabbing the existing dataSource snapshot and adding my items to the end.

Is this the correct use of `dataSource.snapshot()` or is it in fact OK to simply append to an empty snapshot each time?

Comment: Did you figure out the right way? Can you please update?